# EditorFor losing data on post

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-core-mvc

I need some help with this, please!

I have this Model:

```
public class MyModel
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

I have also a EditorTemplate

```
@model MyProject.Models.MyModel

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="@Model.Value" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Value" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Edit View

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures
@model List<MyProject.Models.MyModel>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}
<div class="spaceUnderLogo">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 ">
            <h2>Edit</h2>
            <form id="manageMyModel" asp-controler="MyController" asp-action="Edit" method="post" class="">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <hr />

                    @Html.EditorForModel()

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And MyController has this two methods

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit()
    {

        List<MyModel> model = await GetCurrentInfoAsync();
        return View(model);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(List<MyModel> model)
    {
        // here is where I have the issue
    }
```

As you see I'm having an issue with the post method. When I get the view I send 2 objects: {Id = 1, Name = "A", Value = "9999"} and {Id = 2, Name = "B", Value = null}

Edit B Value property to "8888" and in the Post I'm getting the List only with the Value property like this:
{Id = 0, Name = null, Value = "9999"} and {Id = 0, Name = null, Value = "8888"}

Any idea?

Comment: You're sending the contents of the form via POST, but your form only has an input for the value so that's the only data being sent.  At the very least, you need to add hidden fields for id and name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
@model MyProject.Models.MyModel

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="@Model.Value" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Value" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The trick here is the:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
```

This will ensure that the form contains the value when posted, but there is no editor visible on the form. You will need one of these hidden input for any field that is readonly for the model retrieved by a `GET` in any form submit.